# 特定のサブドメインへの接続ができない。

Tags: dns

以下のようにDNSを設定しているドメインがありますが、サービスを運用しているサブドメインにだけ`ping`したときに`unknown host`になってしまいます。他のサブドメインは解決できるようなのですが、原因がわかりません。
このような場合に考えられる原因はなんでしょうか。ちなみにドメインはnamecheapで取得していてデジタルオーシャンのDNSに転送しています。

DNSレコード

```
TXT subdomain.domain.com Google Search Consoleの文字列
A   *.domain.com         サーバのIPアドレス
NS  domain.com           ns1.digitalocean.com.
NS  domain.com           ns2.digitalocean.com.
NS  domain.com           ns3.digitalocean.com.
```

pingの実行結果

```
ping wrongsubdomain.domain.com => 成功

ping subdomain.domain.com => unknown host
```

Comment: DNS サーバーの仕様によるのかもしれませんが、subdomain.domain.com の TXTレコード設定に何か副作用があるのかもしれません。
明示的に subdomain.domain.com の Aレコードを設定するとどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

通常、問い合わせたサブドメインが存在しない場合に始めて ワイルドカードによる解決が行われます。しかし、今回の場合は `subdomain.domain.com`（のTXTレコード）が存在している為、ワイルドカードによる解決はおこなわれ無いのかもしれません。

次の解説によると「ドメイン名は存在するが、 指定された問い合わせタイプと一致するデータは存在しない」という状態だと思われます。

[IABによる論評:DNSワイルドカードの使用に関するアーキテクチャ上の懸念について - JPNIC](https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/translation/icann/20030920.html)

> ワイルドカードレコードが存在する場合、ルールはさらに複雑になります。 具体的には、問い合わせクラスが一致し、問い合わせドメイン名との完全一致がなく、 問い合わせドメイン名と最も近い一致がワイルドカードである場合、システムは、 ワイルドカードにあるリソースレコードが問い合わせドメイン名であるとみなして、 問い合わせドメイン名と一致するリソースレコードのセットをその場で合成します。 このため、 そのワイルドカードが希望する問い合わせタイプと一致するレコードを持つ場合、 システムは上記の「success」の場合と同様にそのレコードを返します。 そうでない場合は、「no data」の場合と同様に、ドメイン名は存在するが、 指定された問い合わせタイプと一致するデータは存在しない旨を返します。

Aレコードを解決するためには すでに登録している subdomain.domain.com のすべてのレコードを消すか、Aレコードを明示的に設定してみてください。

また、ワイルドカードは正しく使用しないと 予期しない結果になることがあります。
詳しくは 上述の引用元記事をご確認ください。